# Calculating the sum of all k-sized sub-arrays in an array using sliding window algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, array

I need to calculate the sum of all k-sized sub-arrays in an array using sliding window algorithm. Is that a valid sliding window algorithm? If not, why?

```
var sumOfSubArrays = function(arr, k) {
    let currentSubArray = 0;
    for(let i=0; i<k; i++) {
        currentSubArray += arr[i];
    }

    let sum = currentSubArray;
    for(let i=0; i<arr.length-k; i++) {
        current = currentSubArray - arr[i] + arr[i+k];
        sum += current;
        currentSubArray = current;
    }

    return sum;
};

let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
let k = 3;

console.log(sumOfSubArrays(arr, k));
```

Additionally, what could I improve in this code?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, LGTM. That said,

- It unclear what should happen if `k > arr,length`. In any case, better test it before entering the first loop.
- If the sliding window is a requirement, I don't see how it could be improved. Otherwise, if `k` is much smaller than `arr.length` there is a marginally faster approach. Most of the elements, namely from `k` to `n - k`, contribute exactly `k` times. Compute their sum, multiply it by `n - 2*k`, and deal with the lead-in and lead-out separately.
- Give your operator some breathing space. `i < arr.length - k` is more readable than `i<arr.length-k`.

Comment: For those who are wondering, like me, what "LGTM" means: "Looks Good To Me".

Comment: With *most elements contributing exactly k times*, why multiply with `n - 2*k`? That's their number, the weight should be `k`.

Answer (score 0):

A short review;

- You use `var` for the function, I would use `const`, actually I would just use `function` ;)
- I would use a n inline function that can process a *window*, otherwise it's hard to tell that you implemented a sliding window
- I would avoid the word `array` in variable names, unless they are an array
- You never declare `current`, making it a global

Counter-proposal;

```js
function sumSubArrays(list, k){

  const sumWindow = (list) => list.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

  let sum = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i <= list.length-k; i++){
    sum += sumWindow( list.slice(i, i + k) );  
  } 
  return sum;
}



let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
let k = 3;

console.log(27, 27 === sumSubArrays(arr, k));
```